# Android bluetooth communication access modes?

Tags: android, bluetooth, hci, rfcomm, l2cap

When I check the [bluetooth developer page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/wireless/bluetooth.html), it states very clearly that the android api supports the establishment of RFcomm channels. Now, is this mode exclussive for android or does android also support HCI or Bnep (more specifically l2cap)? (Or am I completely wrong and all three are completely different entities?)

Anywho, thank for any help ~Aedon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RFcomm is a higher level protocol than HCI or Bnep, there aren't Android APIs for managing these lower-level protocols.